# release after iPhone navigationController pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am very confused at the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
RPSAdvisorViewController *pushThis = [[RPSAdvisorViewController alloc]init];
pushThis.opponentName = [opponentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pushThis animated:YES];
//[pushThis release];
}
```

The if the line [pushThis release] does not get commented out, the app would crash when I pop back out of that view. I thought I always need to released the viewControllers that I allocated, but this time the app won't let me.

I even tried testing for leaks in instruments like this without releasing pushThis, there are no leaks.

I am really confused, can some one tell me why I'm not suppose to release pushThis?

Edit1: The crash will produce this error message:

-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e66b20

It appears that when the navigationController pops the view controller, it trys to send release to pushThis again, which was already released. If I don't release everything works perfectly, instruments does not show any leaks even if i repeatedly push and pop the view controller.

Comment: You are definitely supposed to release it. Can you paste the console message you see with the cash?

Comment: I've added the error message to the question.

Comment: I can only *guess* that there is some problem with `RPSAdvisorViewController`. Can you try replacing it with a place-holder UIViewController & see what happens?

Comment: Akshay, your suggestion helped me find the bug. in RPSAdvisorViewController I removed the @properties for my UILabels then it worked as it should normally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to release it because when you push view controller, navigation controller take ownership of that controller.

I think there might be some views hierarchy issue with your app.Can you please check that?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that there is some problem with `RPSAdvisorViewController`. Can you try replacing it with a place-holder UIViewController and see what happens?